# Transparent background of HEIC image is black

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, heic

I am changing a PNG image with a transparent background to HEIC format. I want to display the modified image using Android Studio's ImageView. To use the HEIC file I used an asset folder and an ImageDecoder.

However, the transparent background of the HEIC turned black.
I converted png to heic on various sites and exported it using mac preview app, but I couldn't stop the background from turning black. I would appreciate it if you solved.

here's my code:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:layout_width="287dp"
    android:layout_height="557.5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="1.8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:id="@+id/main_character"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

```
val drawable1 = ImageDecoder.decodeDrawable(ImageDecoder.createSource(contextRepo.getValue("main").assets,"anna_character.heic"))

main_character.background = drawable1
```

Comment: why do you use HEIC format?

Comment: check here: https://source.android.com/devices/camera/heif OR You may try WEBP instead.

Comment: I dont' know.. i just ordered..
I heard that heic's size is smaller than png,, so used for performance. Do you have any alternatives besides heic?

Comment: You can use WEBP - https://developer.android.com/studio/write/convert-webp. This is what Google recommends.

Comment: It's best to solve that problem, 
but thank you for providing a good alternative.

Comment: I heard that I can use webp instead of heic. It is better than heic. Thank you very much! 감사합니다!!!